# Need SATA drivers for my Intel® Desktop Board D845GVAD2

Tags: windows-xp, hard-drive, drivers, sata

I have looked at different threads related to creating floppy disks for F6 installation. Like these -

http://communities.intel.com/message/16192#16192

http://communities.intel.com/message/51778#51778

My problem is also same; I have downloaded the drivers from this link

http://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?ProductID=2101&DwnldID=18860&lang=eng&iid=dc_rss

I was trying to integrate this with my Windows XP installation CD using nLite as explained here. I am stuck in the step where I Need to select the textmode driver

[image]

In [Boards product guide](http://downloadmirror.intel.com/15329/eng/D845GVAD2_ProductGuide_English.pdf) ICH4 is mentioned somewhere but all textmode drivers in the list are ICH7 or more. My board is [D845GVAD2](http://www.intel.com/p/en_US/support/highlights/dsktpboards/d845gvad2)
I am not sure which option(s) I should select, Can anyone please guide me with this?

**Update:**

More details on my problem - I wanted to format my hard disk due to virus problems and I deleted all drives including C drive(it prompted me for system/ boot files) and then formatted it with NTFS option. May be I shouldn't have deleted C drive but I am not sure what to do now?

I am getting this msg.

[image]

Comment: I have also posted this question on Intels forum but I am more hopeful of getting something here. http://communities.intel.com/thread/16164

Answer (score 2):

That board (and ICH4) doesn't have SATA. It has the older PATA (IDE) technology - you shouldn't need an F6 floppy disk for the older technology.

See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I/O_Controller_Hub) for more info on ICH.

Edit:
If your setup doesn't work, you could try making your own F6 Floppy Disk from the `Intel Application Accelerator` software. You'll have to download it from Intel - http://downloadcenter.intel.com/detail_desc.aspx?lang=eng&DwnldID=4857. Download `iaa23_multi.exe`.

Then extract `iaa23_multi.exe` to a temporary folder and from that folder run:

```
setup -a -p c:\tempfolder
```

Where tempfolder is a folder of your choice. In tempfolder (or wherever you chose) you will find a folder called `Win2K_XP`. Copy the files from `Win2K_XP` to the root of a floppy disk and use that floppy disk as the driver disk during setup (after pressing F6).

Comment: ok, but then why I am not able to install XP? Also, Why my hard disk is not recognized during setup?

Comment: Is the disk recognized by the BIOS? How is the BIOS configured? (Press F2 to enter BIOS, then go to the Advanced Menu and select IDE Configuration.

Comment: I've added instructions above on how to extract the driver files from the Intel Application Accelerator software.